# Reverse the order of words in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sqlclr

I would like to know how (if it is possible) to reverse the order of **words** returned from a T-SQL string (varchar).

I know about the T-SQL `REVERSE` function. but the function also reverses the letters in the word for example:

Input > `We want to tell you we all love StackOverflow`
Output > `wolfrevOkcatS evol lla ew uoy llet ot tnaw eW`

I want to actually achieve the following in T-SQL:

Input > `We want to tell you we all love StackOverflow`
Output > `Stackoverflow love all we you tell to want We`

The only slightly similar question I found anywhere was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753172/how-to-invert-words-in-a-column/), however that includes splitting comma-separated strings which I do not need to do.

I'm sure there is a way to achieve the above, even if it's a custom function or SQL-CLR function.

---

I managed to split my string up using the following:

```
-- Create a space delimited string for testing
declare @str varchar(max)
select @str = 'We want to tell you we all love StackOverflow'
-- XML tag the string by replacing spaces with </x><x> tags
declare @xml xml
select @xml = cast('<x><![CDATA['+ replace(@str,' ',']]></x><x><![CDATA[') + ']]></x>' as xml)
-- Finally select values from nodes <x> and trim at the same time
select ltrim(rtrim(mynode.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(50)'))) as Code
from (select @xml doc) xx
cross apply doc.nodes('/x') (mynode)
```

The problem now is trying to piece it all back together into one string in a backwards (DESC) order.

Comment: I think you could use the question you quoted - but use " " as the delimiter instead of comma. Once you have the split list it would be easy to manipulate the order.

Comment: Why not use the solution you already found? It was for a comma-separated string, but yours is space-separated, so the only difference is the delimiter (ignoring punctuation issues). More generally, this sort of problem is a common learning or tutorial exercise in many languages, so you might get more out of this task by trying to solve it yourself (in TSQL or a CLR procedure) and then post when you have a specific coding problem and you can show the code you already tried.

Comment: Check this question for various solution to the **`SPLIT()`** function problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql

Comment: The reason I haven't used the question I referenced is because I read that cursors in a production environment is a bad idea? I'm sure there must be an easier solution then the way posted there?

Comment: @Aracas - [See this article for a load of split functions](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Comment: @Aracas: Cursors have a bad reputation because most people use them to loop through SQL resultsets, doing things that could be solved better with a set-based solution. But I see no issues about using a cursor only on a few in-memory variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create one small function in SQL to reverse a string like below:

```
DECLARE @source VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @dest VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @lenght INT

SET @source = 'We want to tell you we all love StackOverflow'
SET @dest = ''

WHILE LEN(@source) > 0
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(' ', @source) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @dest = SUBSTRING(@source,0,CHARINDEX(' ', @source)) + ' ' + @dest
        SET @source = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@source,CHARINDEX(' ', @source)+1,LEN(@source))))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @dest = @source + ' ' + @dest
        SET @source = ''
    END
END
SELECT @dest
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this is one of those cases where a CLR-based solution is going to be better, especially in terms of performance (the solution will invariable make use of iterations and string manipulation).

Here's a few lines of C# that achieves the result, although it has none of the SQL-CLR code you will need:

```
string original = "We want to tell you we all love StackOverflow";
string[] parts = original.Split(' ');

StringBuilder reversedString = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = parts.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    reversedString.Append(parts[i]);
    reversedString.Append(" ");
}

string result = reversedString.ToString();
```

It would be even shorter with LINQ, but I thought I'd keep it simple.  For a T-SQL solution, you can start with the `splitString` function in vzczc's post in the [split post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql) already mentioned.

Based on that, you do this:

```
DECLARE @ReverseString VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ReverseString = ''

SELECT @ReverseString = @ReverseString + s + ' ' 
FROM
(
    SELECT s, zeroBasedOccurance
    FROM dbo.SplitString('We want to tell you we all love StackOverflow', ' ')
) A
ORDER BY A.zeroBasedOccurance DESC

SELECT @ReverseString
```

This should work, but the method it uses for concatenating the string back together is undocumented and may not work correctly in future versions of SQL Server.  It will probably also perform very badly when compared to a CLR solution, so if you have the time to implement that, do so.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @str varchar(100),
        @result varchar(100)

set @str = 'We want to tell you we all love StackOverflow'

;with cte as 
(
select 1 pos_from, charindex(' ', @str) + 1 pos_to
union all
select pos_to, charindex(' ', @str + ' ', pos_to) + 1
from cte
where pos_to <= len(@str)
)
select @result = coalesce( @result + ' ', '') +substring(@str, pos_from, pos_to - pos_from - 1) 
from cte
order by pos_to desc

select @result
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7688373/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server’s native XML support allows for some powerful (and concise) solutions to these sorts of problems:

```
DECLARE @xml XML, @source VARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter VARCHAR(10)

SET @source = 'We want to tell you we all love StackOverflow'
SET @delimiter = ' '
SET @xml = CAST(('<X>' + REPLACE(@source, @delimiter, '</X><X>') + '</X>') AS XML)

SELECT STUFF((SELECT @delimiter + C.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
                FROM @xml.nodes('X') AS X(C)
               ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) DESC
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer is not a function, here is one.

Also I removed the extra useless space generated by the accepted answer

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ReverseWords] (@input VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @output = ''
    WHILE LEN(@input) > 0
    BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX(' ', @input) > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @output = SUBSTRING(@input,0,CHARINDEX(' ', @input)) + ' ' + @output
            SET @input = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@input,CHARINDEX(' ', @input) + 1,LEN(@input))))
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @output = @input + ' ' + @output
            SET @input = ''
        END
    END
    RETURN substring(@output,0, len(@output)) -- remove useless space
END
```

Comment: Thanks John. As heads up, need to add +1 after len(@output), otherwise it cuts off a letter