# Reverse words in string via MySQL functions

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm working with MySQL via WordPress and I would like to sort the title based on its words being in reverse order. For example:

```
Samuel Leroy Jackson -> Jackson Leroy Samuel
Samuel L Jackson     -> Jackson L Samuel
Samuel Jackson       -> Jackson Samuel
Samuel L Jackson Jr  -> Jr Jackson L Samuel
```

I would like to do this via MySQL so that I can sort based on the results.

Comment: You should consider splitting up the data in 2 columns: first and last name.

Comment: Not particularly a good idea to do this in mysql. RDBMSs are not really efficient in text processing. You are better off creating an additional field and use a program to change the order of the words around and save the results in the new field.

Comment: dump into a spreadsheet and split the name and update back to mysql. if this is a one-off.

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @HoneyBadger 100% agree. However, I'm working with an existing project and dataset. Unfortunately, the ambiguity will likely remain.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684818/reverse-the-order-of-words-in-tsql

Though that is for TSQL the MySQL approach should be very similar.

Comment: @Shadow I did not know that they were inefficient with text processing. Definitely something to think about. Sounds like I should add a hook on save and have a special column for sorting to save what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that SQL databases are *inefficient* at text processing, but since SQL tends to treat a column as an atomic value, the operations to work on substrings and other parts of values aren't very *convenient*.

For example, in MySQL, it's kind of awkward to try to split a string into an array. There really isn't an array data type.

The closest thing is [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). You can get a substring based on a character separator. In this case, use a space as the separator.

```
mysql> SET @name = 'Samuel Leroy Jackson';
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ' ', -1) AS `last name`,
    ->        SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ' ', 1) AS `first name`,
    ->        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name, ' ', 2), ' ', -1) AS `middle name`;
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| last name | first name | middle name |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| Jackson   | Samuel     | Leroy       |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

You'll have to work out how to handle cases when you have optional "Jr." or other names with more than three words. I suggest you read the doc I linked to for SUBSTRING_INDEX(), and also take the time to read about other string functions on that same page.

Comment: Downvoter: Please explain why you think this answer is not good. Perhaps I can improve it.

Comment: Adding a more generic version would be great. Meaning, when we have a variable number of words!

Comment: @Enissay, If you're looking for some kind of `string_split()` function, that produces a variable number of columns, MySQL doesn't have a solution for that. In general, SQL requires you to have an explicit expression for each column in the select-list. You can't make a query that appends more columns after the query has started reading data.

Answer (score 1):

The following example will reverse a 3-word string. You can take this example and write similar reversers for 2 and 4 words strings (in case your data is limited to 2-4 words).
Then, you can just run 3 different queries, one for each amount of words (or maybe combine them all with unions) to handle all amounts of words.

As an example, run this to reverse the input *Jackson Leroy Samuel* to the output *Samuel Leroy Jackson*.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Jackson Leroy Samuel', ' ', - 1),
            ' ',
            SUBSTR('Jackson Leroy Samuel',
                INSTR('Jackson Leroy Samuel', ' ') + 1,
                INSTR('Jackson Leroy Samuel', ' ')),
            LEFT('Jackson Leroy Samuel',
                LOCATE(' ', 'Jackson Leroy Samuel') - 1));
```